# How to trace used DLL (is it so-called DLL hell ?)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2008, dll

It should be a simple problem, but I do be stumbled on it. The environment is Visual Studio 2008 on Windows 7, the machine also has vs2010, vs2012 installed. (I have to install several VS because various project uses different version)

I have a simple application uses some 3-rd DLLs. 1). When the app is launched from Vs, it is OK.

2). When I copied the DLLs to execute file and launched it from Explorer, the application crashed on C++ library

Something like:
Program: xxx.exe
File: c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\vector
Line: 779
Expression: vector subscript out of range

3). I opened a command line and add 'Visual Studio 9.0\' and 'Visual Studio 9.0\vc\bin' before PATH environment variable and launched the app, it also crashed.

I've attached to manual launched/crashed process and compared it with Vs IDE lanuched process for modules and PATH environment, it seems same.... I was frustrated.

Any suggestion? Thanks in advanced.

---

I found the reason just now. In Visual Studio, there is a 'Debugging | Working Directory' setting, it is project directory by default. Although I copied all DLLs, I missed some configuration file. It's application logic error.

Comment: Nowadays.. i.e. for the last 10 years at least.. it is recommened to have an installer for your .exe and not rely on copying of DLLs. Copying DLLs will indeed get you in DLL hell.

Comment: @claptrap An installer doesn't really solve anything. It has to copy DLLs too. You need to know which libraries you need, and where to put them.

Comment: What David Heffernan said. Plus, an installer only _obscures_ the actual problem and introduces another element that can possibly fail. The apparent urge for every piece of crap software to come with a rubbish installer that copies incompatible versions of DLLs to the system folder (and overwrites files without asking) is one of the main reasons why Windows has been giving a "tis sux" experience to users for decades.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'vector subscript out of range' issue seems to be more from your code rather than the DLL dependency issue. However, make sure to reference the correct version of the DLLs - Debug/Release.

Comment: I encounter the crash again, it seems this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Use SysInternals's [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to track down, which DLL is loaded.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to debug dependency issues.

You can use it in a static mode, or a dynamic mode (from the Profile menu) to diagnose exactly what the loader is doing at runtime. The latter mode sounds like what you are looking for.